# Use Material-UI HOC in Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to use material UI in my class component, instead of converting everything to Hooks.
I'm not sure which method is easier, Hooks or retro-fitting what I have.

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#higher-order-component-api

Here's my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hits: [],
      desc: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=30.2672&lon=-97.7431&units=imperial&exclude=minutely&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_KEY}`
    )
      .then((json) => json.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          hits: data.current,
          desc: data.current.weather[0],
        });
        console.log(data);
      })

      .catch((error) => console.log("parsing failed", error));
  }

  render() {
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
      root: {
        maxWidth: 450,
        margin: "0 auto",
      },
      MuiCardContent: {
        padding: 0,
        "&:last-child": {
          paddingBottom: 2,
        },
      },
      title: {
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    });

    const unixTimestamp = this.state.hits.sunset * 1000;
    const date = new Date(unixTimestamp);

    const localized = date.toLocaleString();

    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
        <CardContent className={classes.MuiCardContent}>
          <Typography
            className={classes.title}
            color="textSecondary"
            gutterBottom
          >
            Current Weather
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1" component="h2">
            <div>{this.state.desc.main}</div>
            <div>Temp: {this.state.hits.temp} F</div>
            <div>Feels Like: {this.state.hits.feels_like} F</div>
            <div>Humidity: {this.state.hits.humidity}%</div>
            <div>Sunset: {localized}</div>
            <div>UV Index: {this.state.hits.uvi} (Take caution when above 8)</div>
 </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I looked at the material-ui docs, but I'm confused on how to implement this inside of a class component. I'm new to hooks so that seems a bit crazy right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeStyles` returns a **hook** that is only valid with **functional** components. You've correctly found the `withStyles` HOC, but you just need to use it. Factor out and externally define your style object, and pass to the `withStyles()` HOC.

```
...
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'; // <-- import withStyles HOC
...

const styles = {
  root: {
    maxWidth: 450,
    margin: "0 auto",
  },
  MuiCardContent: {
    padding: 0,
    "&:last-child": {
      paddingBottom: 2,
    },
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hits: [],
      desc: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=30.2672&lon=-97.7431&units=imperial&exclude=minutely&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_WEATHER_KEY}`
    )
      .then((json) => json.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          hits: data.current,
          desc: data.current.weather[0],
        });
        console.log(data);
      })

      .catch((error) => console.log("parsing failed", error));
  }

  render() {
    const unixTimestamp = this.state.hits.sunset * 1000;
    const date = new Date(unixTimestamp);
    const localized = date.toLocaleString();

    const { classes } = this.props; // <-- destructure injected classes prop

    return (
      <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
        <CardContent className={classes.MuiCardContent}>
          <Typography
            className={classes.title}
            color="textSecondary"
            gutterBottom
          >
            Current Weather
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1" component="h2">
            <div>{this.state.desc.main}</div>
            <div>Temp: {this.state.hits.temp} F</div>
            <div>Feels Like: {this.state.hits.feels_like} F</div>
            <div>Humidity: {this.state.hits.humidity}%</div>
            <div>Sunset: {localized}</div>
            <div>UV Index: {this.state.hits.uvi} (Take caution when above 8)</div>
 </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App); // <-- decorate App with classes prop
```

Comment: Thank you that helps! I was confused on where to place it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you want to style your class component, you should use withStyles.

Try this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    backgroundColor: "white"
  },
})

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return(
      <div className = {classes.root}>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(useStyles)(App);
```